Абсолютные импорты в Python работают некорректно
Пишу микросервисное приложение на Python FastAPI и столкнулся со следующей проблемой: при попытке абсолютного импорта какого-либо модуля из какой-либо директории самого микросервиса, импорт происходит из аналогичной директории другого микросервиса.
Дерево каталогов прикрепил ниже:

В данном случае пытался в main.py auth-service импортировать schemas следующим образом: from app.schemas import user as user_schemas, а в итоге импорт произошёл из аналогичной директории profile-service.
При этом, если попробовать то же самое провернуть внутри gateway, то там все работает корректно.

Почему не указать полный путь к пакету? from auth-service.app.schemas import user as user_schemas или через __init__ импортировать обращаясь к пакету, что бы не писать полный путь.

первоначально так и хотел, через полный путь, его просто не видит

при чем, если попробовать то же самое провернуть внутри gateway, то там все работает корректно

У меня есть смутное предположение, что пакеты нельзя через дефис именовать. Возможно python воспринимает это как оператор вычитания или тип того... Переименуйте пакет auth-service -> auth_service

да, вы правы, только что это обнаружил и ошибка правда ушла, благодарю за помощь!

Может я и ошибаюсь, но импорты одного и того же на самом деле не должны как-то напрягать Питон. Он первый раз импортирует, а потом будет игнорировать. А вообще, мне нравится как люди борются с импортами. Не первый раз читаю и ехидно хихикаю. Вместо того, чтоб сесть и один раз подумать, борются...

Открыв PEP 8 - вот что прочитал:
Package and Module Names

Modules should have short, all-lowercase
names. Underscores can be used in the module name if it improves
readability. Python packages should also have short, all-lowercase
names, although the use of underscores is discouraged.

Перевод:
Имена пакетов и модулей

Модули должны иметь короткие имена, состоящие
полностью из строчных букв. Подчеркивания можно использовать в имени
модуля, если это улучшает читаемость. Пакеты Python также должны иметь
короткие имена, состоящие полностью из строчных букв,
использование подчеркиваний не рекомендуется.

Хоть в PEP 8 ничего про - не было написано, но как я понимаю причину по которой их не используют в названиях модулей/пакетов, связана с тем, что дефис (минус) является оператором в Python, что соответственно и вызывает ошибку импорта.
Так что согласно рекомендациям, нужно использовать такое название пакета:  authservice.
Менее предпочтительное имя с подчеркиванием: auth_service

"Менее предпочтительное имя с подчеркиванием" - почему вы решили, что это менее предпочтительное имя? Это же два слова, написание их слитно ухудшает читаемость.

Исходя из предложения ..although the use of underscores is discouraged.

А, ну значит это дичь в PEP8 написана.

Решение было найдено, по какой-то причине все имена, которые содержали дефис, работали некорректно. После переименования все работает как надо

Не по какой-то причине, а потому что это не дефис, а минус. Вы куски имени друг от друга вычитать так пытаетесь.
